# Enable compiler warning for initiating member variables with themselves

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, warnings

Is there a compiler warning under gcc and/or vs to detect member variables initiated to themselves?

gcc has -Winit-self, but only seems to work for

```
int f()
{
    int i = i;
    return i;
}
```

and not for

```
class A {
    int m; 
public:
    A(int) : m(m) { } 
    int f() {return m;} 
};
```

**Edit**: Take the question back, all that was missing was an -O1 or above (Thanks @honk)

**Edit 2**: Actually, the problem is back on the table. In a simplistic example -O1 -Wuninitialized -Winit-self works, however, it catches it not at the point where you declare `m(m)` but rather when you define `A(4)`. This also means that the compiler doesn't pick up on it if the constructor is in its own compilation unit (which I would imagine should be rather often in real world scenarios).

Comment: I compile everything with -Wall. I believe that the people that wrote the compiler knows more about the ins and outs of the language than myself, and also that the compile is more able that me to pick up a variety of potential problems. As Scott Myers (whose books I recommend reading) that you should take heed but not rely on them.

Comment: @EdHeal: -Winit-self is not included in -Wall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There don't seem to be any compiler flags either under msvc or gcc. However, with gcc, valgrind picks up on any use of uninitiated variables, which sorts the problem. Not certain of a solution for Windows. Visual Studio Code Analysis looks like it might pick it up, but that is no available in the base versions.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this in function:

```
int i = i;
```

then I think, you could use `-Wuninitialized` option with GCC, as it is *using* uninitialized variable `i` to initialize `i`.  Same with member variable in your code.

Also note that this code invokes undefined behavior. However, if you do that for variables at namespace level, then that is well-defined.

Comment: Worth noting that this also needs some optimization, e.g. `-O2` and is included in `-Wall`.

Comment: @Nawaz: There is something going on with -Wuninitialized and -Winit-self, as can be read [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34772), but in any case in neither combination do these warn about member variables initialized to themselves.

Comment: @Cookie: Are you using any optimization flags? Try using it!